# How to clear input formatting in ckeditor django?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

Need to format all input data to the ckeditor rich field. 
Tried to do next in my `config.js`

```
config.pasteAsPlainText = true;
```

and

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

but all my input text doesn't clear its formatting. I need to clear all styles, colors, etc.
How I can implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true; - this was true way. But need to put it to the setting.py to the CKEDITOR_CONFIGS dict, not to the config.js